# Nested JSONModel in iOS to get info from Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, jsonmodel

I'm working with [**JSONModel**](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) to parse Instagram info from JSON to a model in my iOS app. I have tried many ways to achieve it but I can't. Three main parts of the response are **data**, **meta** and **pagination**. I have created the model and the model is always NULL. I'm going to attach the response I'm trying to parse, my models and how I'm processing the response. I think it could be a problem with the structure but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

**Response from Instagram**

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
            "attribution": null,
            "caption": {
                "created_time": "1387987595",
                "from": {
                    "full_name": "Camilo Sacanamboy",
                    "id": "268167404",
                    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_268167404_75sq_1386784112.jpg",
                    "username": "csacanam"
                },
                "id": "618807262892627401",
                "text": "Navidad :)"
            },
            "comments": {
                "count": 2,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "created_time": "1387987956",
                        "from": {
                            "full_name": "Luisa Bellydancer",
                            "id": "548519361",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_548519361_75sq_1398196543.jpg",
                            "username": "luisacantillo"
                        },
                        "id": "618810289837938356",
                        "text": "Te amo beb\u00e9"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1403666639",
                        "from": {
                            "full_name": "Camilo Sacanamboy",
                            "id": "268167404",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_268167404_75sq_1386784112.jpg",
                            "username": "csacanam"
                        },
                        "id": "750332614214522476",
                        "text": "#sacanamboy"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "created_time": "1387987595",
            "filter": "Walden",
            "id": "618807262548694878_268167404",
            "images": {
                "low_resolution": {
                    "height": 306,
                    "url": "http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/1515365_559830227444878_1414305160_a.jpg",
                    "width": 306
                },
                "standard_resolution": {
                    "height": 640,
                    "url": "http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/1515365_559830227444878_1414305160_n.jpg",
                    "width": 640
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "height": 150,
                    "url": "http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpf1/t51.2885-15/1515365_559830227444878_1414305160_s.jpg",
                    "width": 150
                }
            },
            "likes": {
                "count": 2,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "full_name": "Luisa Bellydancer",
                        "id": "548519361",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_548519361_75sq_1398196543.jpg",
                        "username": "luisacantillo"
                    },
                    {
                        "full_name": "Steven Zambrano",
                        "id": "198842014",
                        "profile_picture": "http://photos-d.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10354559_1419915091614315_879045002_a.jpg",
                        "username": "steven_zambrano"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "link": "http://instagram.com/p/iWce08pZde/",
            "location": null,
            "tags": [
                "sacanamboy"
            ],
            "type": "image",
            "user": {
                "bio": "",
                "full_name": "Camilo Sacanamboy",
                "id": "268167404",
                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_268167404_75sq_1386784112.jpg",
                "username": "csacanam",
                "website": ""
            },
            "users_in_photo": [
                {
                    "position": {
                        "x": 0.39722222,
                        "y": 0.15416667
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "full_name": "Luisa Bellydancer",
                        "id": "548519361",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_548519361_75sq_1398196543.jpg",
                        "username": "luisacantillo"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "position": {
                        "x": 0.55138886,
                        "y": 0.09583333
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "full_name": "Camilo Sacanamboy",
                        "id": "268167404",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_268167404_75sq_1386784112.jpg",
                        "username": "csacanam"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribution": null,
            "caption": {
                "created_time": "1391910835",
                "from": {
                    "full_name": "Camilo Sacanamboy",
                    "id": "268167404",
                    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_268167404_75sq_1386784112.jpg",
                    "username": "csacanam"
                },
                "id": "651717783438333290",
                "text": "Vista de Bogot\u00e1"
            },
            "comments": {
                "count": 1,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "created_time": "1403665438",
                        "from": {
                            "full_name": "Camilo Sacanamboy",
                            "id": "268167404",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_268167404_75sq_1386784112.jpg",
                            "username": "csacanam"
                        },
                        "id": "750322542532990878",
                        "text": "#sacanamboy"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "created_time": "1391910835",
            "filter": "Hudson",
            "id": "651717782742079012_268167404",
            "images": {
                "low_resolution": {
                    "height": 306,
                    "url": "http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-15/1889287_611340528913277_403885343_a.jpg",
                    "width": 306
                },
                "standard_resolution": {
                    "height": 640,
                    "url": "http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-15/1889287_611340528913277_403885343_n.jpg",
                    "width": 640
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "height": 150,
                    "url": "http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfp1/t51.2885-15/1889287_611340528913277_403885343_s.jpg",
                    "width": 150
                }
            },
            "likes": {
                "count": 3,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "full_name": "Luisa Bellydancer",
                        "id": "548519361",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_548519361_75sq_1398196543.jpg",
                        "username": "luisacantillo"
                    },
                    {
                        "full_name": "Stiven Sepulveda Casta\u00f1o",
                        "id": "270408040",
                        "profile_picture": "http://photos-a.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xfp1/10354393_1459814907595448_1770710968_a.jpg",
                        "username": "johntato"
                    },
                    {
                        "full_name": "Julian Garcia",
                        "id": "318551590",
                        "profile_picture": "http://photos-e.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xaf1/10413240_284995708339980_626057267_a.jpg",
                        "username": "juliangarcia20"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "link": "http://instagram.com/p/kLXd7WJZYk/",
            "location": {
                "id": 1187760,
                "latitude": 4.67413252,
                "longitude": -74.037993338,
                "name": "Mirador de La Calera, Bogota"
            },
            "tags": [
                "sacanamboy"
            ],
            "type": "image",
            "user": {
                "bio": "",
                "full_name": "Camilo Sacanamboy",
                "id": "268167404",
                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_268167404_75sq_1386784112.jpg",
                "username": "csacanam",
                "website": ""
            },
            "users_in_photo": [
                {
                    "position": {
                        "x": 0.3625,
                        "y": 0.54444444
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "full_name": "Luisa Bellydancer",
                        "id": "548519361",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_548519361_75sq_1398196543.jpg",
                        "username": "luisacantillo"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "position": {
                        "x": 0.60694444,
                        "y": 0.42222223
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "full_name": "Camilo Sacanamboy",
                        "id": "268167404",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_268167404_75sq_1386784112.jpg",
                        "username": "csacanam"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "pagination": {
        "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
        "min_tag_id": "1403666639684031",
        "next_min_id": "1403666639684031"
    }
}
```

**Models**

```
    @interface TagPicturesInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray<PictureInstagram> *data;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) MetaInstagram *meta;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) PaginationInstagram *pagination;
    @end

    @protocol PictureInstagram
    @end
    @interface PictureInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *attribution;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) CaptionInstagram *caption;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) CommentsInstagram *comments;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *created_time;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *filter;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *id;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) ImagesInstagram *images;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) LikesInstagram *likes;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *link;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) LocationInstagram<Optional> *location;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray<Optional> *tags;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *type;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) UserInstagram *user;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray<UserInPhoto> *users_in_photo;
    //@property (assign,nonatomic) BOOL user_has_liked;
    //@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *website;
    @end

    @interface MetaInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (assign,nonatomic) int code;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *error_type;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *error_message;
    @end

    @interface PaginationInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *next_max_tag_id;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *deprecation_warning;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *next_max_id;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *next_min_id;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *min_tag_id;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *next_url;
    @end

    @interface CaptionInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *created_time;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) FromInstagram *from;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *id;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *text;
    @end

    @interface CommentsInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (assign,nonatomic) int count;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray<CommentInstagram> *data;
    @end


    @interface ImagesInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (strong,nonatomic) ImgInstagram *low_resolution;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) ImgInstagram *standard_resolution;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) ImgInstagram *thumbnail;
    @end

    @interface LikesInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (assign,nonatomic) int count;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray<FromInstagram> *data;
    @end

    @interface LocationInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (assign,nonatomic) int id;
    @property (assign,nonatomic) double latitude;
    @property (assign,nonatomic) double longitude;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *name;
    @end

    @interface UserInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *bio;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *full_name;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *id;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *profile_picture;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *username;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString<Optional> *website;
    @end

    @interface UserInPhoto : JSONModel
    @property (strong,nonatomic) PositionTagInstagram *position;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) FromInstagram *user;
    @end

    @protocol FromInstagram
    @end
    @interface FromInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *full_name;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *id;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *profile_picture;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *username;
    @end

    @protocol CommentInstagram
    @end
    @interface CommentInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *created_time;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) FromInstagram *from;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *id;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *text;
    @end

    @protocol ImgInstagram
    @end
    @interface ImgInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (assign,nonatomic) double height;
    @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *url;
    @property (assign,nonatomic) double width;
    @end

    @interface PositionTagInstagram : JSONModel
    @property (assign,nonatomic) double x;
    @property (assign,nonatomic) double y;
    @end
```

**Getting response with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)**

```
-(void) loadInstagramInfo
{
    //1. Create request
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", BaseURLString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //2. Do request with AFNetworking
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *json = [responseObject description];
        NSError *err = nil;
        self.pictures = [[TagPicturesInstagram alloc]initWithString:json error:&err];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error cargando fotos");
        /*
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
         message:[error localizedDescription]
         delegate:nil
         cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
         otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alertView show];*/
    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: You should have changed the URL of images. (PS nice pics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I created one .txt file with your json response and then fetch data that you required.**

```
NSMutableArray *arrayData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"json.txt"];
//    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"json = %@",json);

    for (NSDictionary* dic in [json objectForKey:@"data"]) {
        [arrayData addObject:dic];
    }


    NSLog(@"array data = %@",arrayData);
    NSLog(@"meta code = %@",[[json valueForKey:@"meta"] valueForKey:@"code"]);
    NSLog(@"pagination deprecation_warning = %@",[[json valueForKey:@"pagination"] valueForKey:@"deprecation_warning"]);
    NSLog(@"pagination min_tag_id = %@",[[json valueForKey:@"pagination"] valueForKey:@"min_tag_id"]);
    NSLog(@"pagination next_min_id = %@",[[json valueForKey:@"pagination"] valueForKey:@"next_min_id"]);
```

follow above code and do changes in your model. Hope this will help you.

This is a response string.

meta code = 200

pagination deprecation_warning = next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead

pagination deprecation_warning = 1403666639684031

pagination deprecation_warning = 1403666639684031